# Help Me Create an Anthropology/Sociology SE!

Tags: discussion

If any of you would be interested in a Anthropology/Sociology SE please check out the proposal on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/118029/sociology-and-anthropology?referrer=HP-flEVIPwZLIq8hLBIWoA2).

It would be great if any of you could post some example questions or critique the ones that are already posted in order to better define the SE. I think this would be a great SE for the platform since alot of questions that get asked in the History, Politics, and Philosophy Stack Exchanges often fall within the realms of Anthro/Socio and could be better answered on a platform specifically for those topics.

Nowadays these areas of study are becoming more and more important in the political, social, and cultural spheres, I think it's really important that we try to decrease misinformation and increase discourse on these subjects.

Thanks!

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Sociology and Anthropology]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a question, it is a request for help.  That said, I think it is worth examining the impact of the change on H:SE

The good news is that we would have a place to redirect questions on Anthro and sociology.  The bad news is that we'd have to redirect anthro and sociology questions.

We would need to create a dividing line/rule of thumb to distinguish between the two types of questions. At least notionally, I'd assume that: History keeps Questions on historiography, questions about events & individuals; Anthrosoc gets all questions that deal with cultural groups. Easy to say, but I suspect rather difficult to implement.\

Which forum would be the "correct" place to host the following recent questions?

- Was race really unimportant in times past? *Although I would be thrilled to migrate all questions on race to AnthroSoc*
- How did the first Sunday, or the first Sabbath day, become established? *tricky question - we closed this because we don't understand it.  "Sabbath" is a social construct, and might belong more properly in AnthroSoc. But I think that the principle of "only migrate quality" would apply*
- Sources of iron in the middle east *is this sociology or history*?

Comment: At the end of the day it is your decision to close a question if it seems like it should be answered something else. I'd say that if a fair argument cam be made that it belongs here theres no harm in keeping ir open.

Comment: Might be just me, and without getting into the quality of the questions, but your three examples all strike me as about history.

Comment: "Sources of iron" is imho 1. geology 2. applied to history. "What about "History of Sociology"? History is by its very nature interdisciplinary. In case of *doubt* where a Q belongs it will always be a dance on the line, or around it. This probably is not bad, see the spectrum of SuperUser, Unix, Ubuntu; or Hermeneutics and Christianity; or… As long as good Qs find their home somewhere, and answers. – That said, I see a huge possible overlap. So I feel your pain that good news are the same news as bad news.

Comment: Mod policy is above my paygrade, but speaking personally I know that when I have a borderline question I target it to the SE community I most want an answer from; in other words, when I come to History SE I'm not just there because I have an historically oriented question, but also because I want an historically oriented answer. With that in mind, if the classification of a question is ambiguous I suggest trusting the poster's original choice, and assuming that the desire for an historical take on the question is implicit in the post.

Comment: (and that was when I realized this post was already a year old ... oops.)

Comment: @Era This is Stack Exchange. There is no Mod Policy: site policies are determined by user consensus and executed by the community whenever possible and by mods as only when absolutely necessary. If Mark hated Anthro.se and didn't want to migrate anything, but the community decided anything tagged anthro gets migrated, I trust he would still do it. And if he didn't users would call him out on Meta. Sure, appointed or elected mods are usually chosen so because of their leadership skills, but they only facilitate decisions, not make them. As a wise philosopher once said, "The power... is yours!!"

Comment: "The bad news is that we'd have to redirect anthro and sociology questions." No, there is no such rule in Stack Exchange. Sites are not required to migrate away questions that are on topic elsewhere. All that matters is whether the community where the question was originally posed considers the question on topic.